# How to replace domain in haproxy request?

Tags: haproxy

is it possible to change/rewrite/replace the domain name in the request before you pass it through to the backend server?

I have 1 frontend:

```
frontend https-dev
        maxconn 2000
        option forwardfor header X-Real-IP
        http-request set-header X-Real-IP %[src]
        default_backend be-dev-cdn

        # BEGIN CORS
        http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, JSNLog-RequestId, activityId, applicationId, applicationUserId, channelId, senderId, sessionId"
        http-response set-header Access-Control-Max-Age 3628800
        http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, POST, PUT"
        # END CORS

        bind *:443 ssl crt domain.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        # set X-SSL in case of ssl_fc <- explained below
        http-request set-header X-SSL %[ssl_fc]
```

And 1 backend with multiple hosts:

```
backend be-dev-cdn
        balance roundrobin
        server dev-cdn01.domain.com 192.168.101.1:80 check
        server dev-cdn02.domain.com 192.168.101.2:80 check
        server dev-cdn03.domain.com 192.168.101.3:80 check
        server dev-cdn04.domain.com 192.168.101.4:80 check
        server dev-cdn05.domain.com 192.168.101.5:80 check
```

The user would input the domain **[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)** and I would then rewrite/replace this domain to a new domain name based on the backend server to which the request is forwarded. For example:
[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) -> haproxy -> backend server dev-cdn05.domain.com; rewrite the request.

My goal is that I would just like to route the requests through haproxy server but not the response

Is this possible with haproxy?

Comment: rewrite domain - yes - it's just `host` header to rewrite. proxy requests, but not responses? how do you imagine that to work and why? proxy (haproxy or other) makes a connection on client's behalf to backend and serves that client a response it gets from backend. HTTP serves response on the same TCP connection as request. maybe some HTTP rewrites to different domains could do it?

Comment: I don't want to route the traffic back through haproxy from the cdn.